# .NET core SDK versions

Tags: .net, linux

Currently I'm trying to get .net core to work in my RHEL 7 machine. Now I'm almost there but have one problem.

For my normal user with command

```
dontet --version
```

I can see `1.0.4` which is OK. But same command with 'sudo' gives me `1.0.0-preview2-1-003177`.

How can I get correct version for sudo as well?

Answer (score 0):

That's an interesting problem.  I don't know the answer right now, but there are a few things we might do to help us find it.

Please try running 'env' as both your normal user and via sudo to see if there are difference in the path.